# Prove that a.e. convergence on a $\sigma$-finite measure space $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ implies uniform convergence on a sequence of measurable sets.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am currently reading the book "Modern Real Analysis" by Ziemer and have come to an exercise I am having trouble with. The exercise appears in the chapter on measurable functions within the section on approximation of measurable functions. The exercise statement goes :

> Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and suppose that
> $f$, $f_{k}$, $k=1,2,...$, are measurable functions that are finite almost everywhere and :
> \begin{equation}
> \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} f_{k}(x) = f(x)
> \end{equation}
> for $\mu$ almost all $x \in X$. Prove that there are measurable sets $E_{0},E_{1},E_{2},...$, such that $\mu(E_{0}) = 0$
> \begin{equation}
> X = \bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty} E_{i}
> \end{equation}
> and $\{f_{k}\} \rightarrow f$ uniformly on each $E_{i}$, $i > 0$.

The following theorem appears in the text of the chapter :

> Theorem 5.18 (Egorov)
> Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a finite measure space and suppose $\{ f_{i} \}$
> and $f$ are measurable functions that are finite almost everywhere
> on $X$. Also, suppose that $\{ f_{i} \}$ converges pointwise a.e. to
> $f$. Then for each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a set $A \in \mathcal{M}$ such
> that $\mu(\tilde{A}) < \epsilon$ and $\{f_{i}\} \rightarrow f$ uniformly
> on $A$.

Here the notation $A^{c}$ and $\tilde{A}$ represent the complement of $A$.

Here is my solution so far :

We know that since $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ is $\sigma$-finite that $\exists \{ A_{i} \}_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathcal{M}$
s.t. $\mu(A_{i}) < \infty \; \forall i \in \mathbb{N}$ and :
\begin{equation}
X = \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_{i}
\end{equation}
Define :
\begin{equation}
\Gamma_{f}(x) := \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} f_{k}(x) = f(x)
\end{equation}
Let :
\begin{equation}
D = \{ x \in X \; \mid \; \neg \Gamma_{f}(x) \}
\end{equation}
We know $\mu(D) = 0$. (Note that $D$ is null and therefore measurable).

Let :
\begin{equation}
E_{0} = \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} (D \cap A_{i})
\end{equation}
We see that :
\begin{equation}
A_{i} \in \mathcal{M} \text{ and } D \in \mathcal{M} \text{ and } E_{0} \subset D \Rightarrow E_{0} \in \mathcal{M} \text{ and } \mu(E_{0}) = 0 
\end{equation}
Now let :
\begin{equation}
E_{i} = A_{i} \cap D^{c} \; \forall i \geq 1
\end{equation}
We know $A_{i} \in \mathcal{M}$ and $D \in \mathcal{M}$ implies $E_{i} \in \mathcal{M}$. We also see :
\begin{align}
X = \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_{i} 
 & = \left( D \cap \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_{i} \right) \cup \left( D^{c} \cap \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_{i} \right)\\
 & = \left[ \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} (A_{i} \cap D) \right] \cup \left[ \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} (A_{i} \cap D^{c}) \right]\\
 & = E_{0} \cup \left[ \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} E_{i} \right]\\
 & = \bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty} E_{i}
\end{align}
We also know :
\begin{equation}
\Gamma_{f}(x) \; \forall x \in D^{c} \Rightarrow \Gamma_{f}(x) \; \forall x \in E_{i} \text{ , } \forall i \geq 1
\end{equation}
Also :
\begin{equation}
\mu(A_{i}) < \infty \text{ and } E_{i} \subset A_{i} \; \forall i \geq 1 \Rightarrow \mu(E_{i}) < \infty \; \forall i \geq 1
\end{equation}
So by theorem 5.18 we have for each $i \geq 1$ :
\begin{equation}
\epsilon > 0 \Rightarrow \exists H \in \mathcal{M} \text{ s.t. } H \subset E_{i} \text{ and } f_{i} \rightarrow f \text{ uniformly on } E_{i} \setminus H \text{ and } \mu(H) < \epsilon
\end{equation}
This means that $f_{k} \rightarrow f$ almost uniformly on each $E_{i}$. But how can I show that $f_{k} \rightarrow f$ converges uniformly on
each $E_{i}$ ?

Can anyone help with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the theorem of Egorov  we have for each $n$ a set $E_n$ such that
$$
\mu(X\setminus E_n)<\frac{1}{n}
$$
and $f_k\to f$ uniformly on $E_n$. It is easy to see that $f_k\to f$ uniformly on $E_n\cup E_{n+1}$ and
$$
\mu(X\setminus (E_n\cup E_{n+1}))<\frac{1}{n+1}.
$$
This allows to choose the sequence of sets $E_n$ being increasing. It follows that $X\setminus E_n$ is decreasing and therefore,
$$
\mu\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^N(X\setminus E_n)\right)=\mu(X\setminus E_N)<\frac{1}{N}\,.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\mu\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (X\setminus E_n)\right)=0
$$
and we can set
$$E_0=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (X\setminus E_n)\,.$$

The sequence $E_0,E_1,...$ now satisfies all requirements from the exercise.